# Enabling Dual Channel mode: do the RAM sticks have to be identical?

Tags: memory, dual-channel

My current machine has 3 GB RAM, one 1GB stick and one 2 GB stick.  If I buy another 2 GB stick, does it have to be the exact same brand as the 2 GB stick already installed? Or can they be different brands and still be identical (DDR2, etc)?

I'm looking at the 2 GB options on this page for a Dell 1735: http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&Configurator=MemoryConfigurator&CFG=CFG001M595821|1735&DEPA=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure they have to be the same size and speed, but not necessarily identical.

Comment: Yes, with the same timings. +1 for you.

Comment: note: there are a lot of little parameters about RAM that should match timing/cs.  it is possible to use non-identical sticks, but I always order from kingston so I can get identical sticks and lessen my possible headache or picky mobos...+1 just the same as you are technically correct

Comment: The best *kind* of correct!